# How to change a specific column data using hooks in Node.js? (Sequelize, Postgresql)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, migration, sequelize.js

I added a new column to my old table in postgresql database using migrations and assigned default value for that column.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return Promise.all([
      queryInterface.addColumn(
        'notifications', // table name
        'flag', // new field name
        {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          defaultValue: 0,
          allowNull: false,
        },
      ),
    ]);
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  }
};
```

Now i want to change to specific values of that column. How can i do that with hooks or service? I am new at node.js, i will really appreciate your help.

My notifications.model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;


module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const notifications = sequelizeClient.define('notifications', {
    senderId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    recipientId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    notificationtype: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    postId:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:true
    },
    conversationId:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:true
    }
  },
  
  );
  return notifications;
};
```

This is my notifications.hooks.js.
What should i add to update the flag to 1?

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;
const authHooks = require('feathers-authentication-hooks');

const { fastJoin, discard, disallow } = require('feathers-hooks-common');

const acquireNotification = require('../../hooks/notifications/acquire_notification');
const relateWithUser = require('../../hooks/notifications/relate_with_users');


const reverse = require('../../hooks/common/reverse');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    
    all: [
      authenticate('jwt'),
      
      reverse(),
      

    ],
    find: [
      acquireNotification(),
      reverse()
    ],
    get: [
      acquireNotification()
    ],
    create: [
      authHooks.associateCurrentUser({
        idField: 'id',
        as: 'senderId'
      }),
    ],
    update: [
    ],
    patch: [
    ],
    remove: [
    ]
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [
      fastJoin(relateWithUser),
    ],
    get: [],
    create: [
      fastJoin(relateWithUser),
    ],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you wish to update some records and set `flag` field value for those records to a specified value?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to do that :/

Comment: Do you define models using Sequelize? If so show them

Comment: I edit my question to show

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `flag` column to `notifications` model:

```js
flag:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false
    }
```

And then you can update some records with specific conditions like this:

```js
await notifications.update({
  flag: 1 // desired value
}, {
  where: {
    notificationtype: 'type' // indicate a desired condition here
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but i can not add this to my hooks, Can you please check out my question again? I added my hooks.js